# How to take screenshot of each link clicked in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to click links in a webpage by storing it in array and click this links one after another and take entire screenshot of each and every link after clicked,and all this i have to do only in SELENIUM IDE...how to do that?? 
I know up to save links in array and clicking links, but failed to capture screenshot of each page after clicking..because it is taking only one screenshot and overwriting that screenshot when second link clicked..

Comment: How many links you have and how many screenshots to be taken? This is possibile. Reason I ask this question is because if you have only lesser links & screenshots then this can be done without any loop and readcsv in selenium. If you have more then you can do with loop and readcsv.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason why your screenshots are being overwritten is because you have a consistent image file name for them. Try something like this:

Command:

```
 captureEntirePageScreenshotAndWait;
```

Target:

```
 C:\\<Directory>\\different-filename-for-screenshot.png
```

and so on and so forth...

Answer (score 0):

If you have very less screens to capture then you can simply capture them in different file names. Please refer example below.

[LessScreenshot IDE Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr8Ox.jpg)

[LessScreenshot Files stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqbBG.jpg)

If you have more screens to capture then you can read the file locations and names from CSV file. For more information about loop and readCSV, please refer [this link](http://bashamy.blogspot.com/2016/01/selenium-ide-to-use-while-loop-and-read.html). In the example below, I have capture 7 clicks screenshots.

[Input_CSV_File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRMvY.jpg)

[IDE_Script_Loop&ReadCSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOXnK.jpg)

[Screenshot captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMgqY.jpg)

Comment: Thank u Abdul it is very helpful, i m doing syntax mistake.